# reformulation of mathematics using set theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, education

What reading / mooc / online video etc would you recommend for an software engineer who wants to understand the reformulation of mathematics using set theory. My background is in machine learning, signal and image processing with good knowledge of Calculus, linear algebra, functional analysis, Fourier analysis and a taste for math :)

EDIT: What I know is that the movement started in the 19th century and into the 20th century with the reformulation of Calculus. The motivation was, I believe, to give Calculus a foundation based on Logic to avoid contradictions (I don't recall what the contradictions or paradoxes were).

Comment: Do you mean by "reformulation of mathematics using set theory" the history of the movement? the foundations of mathematics? or a modern (i.e. non engineering/cookbook) treatment of Linear algebra, functional analysis, ... using set theory?

Comment: I think the foundations of mathematics is closest. I can read the history, but I want to understand how Calculus can be reformulated using set theory. A bit of history can aid understanding too.

Comment: Maybe wikipedia would be a good warmup ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory It's hard to answer precisely to your question. What is your goal ? Coding a "calculator" (e.g. Mathematica style ?) or a "proof generator" (e.g. Coq style ?)

Comment: I don't understand the hold on my question. I did say I'm an engineer not a mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the text of your edit it sounds like you want to study rigorous analysis. I would recommend "A radical approach to real analysis" by Bressoud as it takes a historical approach and teaches the math along with the history of the overhaul in the 19th century you are alluding to. You might also appreciate the fact that he motivates things with the familiar problem of trigonometric series that was quite controversial in the 19th century.

I wouldn't characterize it as a 'reformulation using set theory' (although any treatment nowadays uses set notation and has some amount of set theory in it.) The rigorous approach to calculus actually came first and set theory was born out of it. (Cantor came upon the concept when he was studying the uniqueness of trigonometric series!)

Comment: I like some of the reviews about the book and it does seem that this is what I'm looking for. Will read it and update the question again once I actually know enough to be more specific, but this looks like an excellent recommendation. I've seen some discussions on which edition to get 1st or 2nd, with some people favoring the first. Which would you recommend?